# How do I access GetGlobalResourceObject function from a class that is not a page?

Tags: asp.net, resources, httpcontext

I have a class in my asp.net proj, I would like to get access GetGlobalResourceObject (that page exposes), from anywhere in the site, possible?

In other words I wanna access the global resources from a class that is not a page I don't care how.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Answer:
Yes, as following pseudo:

```
Resources.<The name of the resources file name>.<your resource key>;
```

Example:

```
lblTitle.Text = Resources.MySettings.WebsiteTitle;
```

`Resources` is an Visual-Studio auto generated namespace that exposes all the global resource classes and props in the project.

Comment: Hi,
Can I use   (string)this.GetGlobalResourceObject("Resources", "COL_Description")
as like below in label or button text
 <asp:Label ID="lblTest" runat="server" Text='<%# (string)this.GetGlobalResourceObject("Resources", "COL_Description")%>'></asp:Label>

Answer (score 16):

You should use

```
HttpContext.GetGlobalResourceObject("myResourceKey")
```

...because that way it will still work when using a custom ResourceProvider. The default type-generator for Resource files explicitely uses the Resx provider and won't work if you implement something like a [database provider](http://www.west-wind.com/presentations/wwDbResourceProvider/).

Comment: I preferer "httpcontext" instead of the visual studio generated namespace, because I can pass a culture parameter and choose which language to return.  Using the "direct" namespace function, I always get english, I need to change the current thread culture before calling it if I want the good culture.

Comment: Hi,
Can I use   (string)this.GetGlobalResourceObject("Resources", "COL_Description")
as like below in label or button text
 <asp:Label ID="lblTest" runat="server" Text='<%# (string)this.GetGlobalResourceObject("Resources", "COL_Description")%>'></asp:Label>

Answer (score 2):

On some farms you'll need to wrap the call to

```
HttpContext.GetGlobalResourceObject("myResourceKey")
```

inside a try/catch block to get it over the "Could not find any resources appropriate for the specified culture or the neutral culture" error.

Comment: Hey, this works alright, i use the following code:                                           `var resource = HttpContext.GetGlobalResourceObject("ResourceBaseName", "ResourceKey");
string message = resource != null ? resource.ToString() : string.Empty; `

Answer (score 1):

If you are in the site you have access to HttpContext and can use:

```
HttpContext.GetGlobalResourceObject("myResourceKey")
```

Comment: I think Resources is better since it's strongly typed, rather than that object finction.
thanks anyway

Comment: @MrFox use the answer above: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1107906/how-do-i-access-getglobalresourceobject-function-from-a-class-that-is-not-a-page/1107915#1107915

Comment: +1 for data-driven keys. There are cases where the key is unknown at compile time, e.g., read from a database or a user-selection. `HttpContext.GetGlobalResourceObject(resourceKey);` where `resourceKey` is a string set earlier in the code.

Answer (score -3):

I kinda took this from the resource designer,

```
ResourceManager temp = 
  new ResourceManager("Resources.<<resource name>>", 
    System.Reflection.Assembly.Load("App_GlobalResources"));
```

Comment: The code in the designer is used to initiate the static member, so the resource-assembly is loaded once per instance, then user accesses the tools given by MSFT to access the initiated member. Using your line will retrieve the resource over and over from the assembly, which should be avoided. Anyhow, the line you posted loads the ResourceManager and does not get the desired property which is what the OP wants.